# How do you escape special characters in SQL Where clause?

Tags: sql, jdbc

How do you escape special characters in SQL Where clause? The SLASH (/) specifically. I can make it work with "LIKE" but I need the SQL to match the exact URL since `"/path/to/file/"` returns both rows:

URLs in database:

```
"/path/to/file/"
"/path/to/file/*/"

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");
sb.append("WHERE URL LIKE '%" + url + "%'");

return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(sb.toString(), new MyTableMapper());
```

Comment: `URL LIKE '%/path/to/file/%'` is expected to return both those rows.

Comment: If it works using `LIKE` why can't you simply use `=` instead? Or remove the `%`? Btw, the Slash is not a special character in SQL.

Comment: If you want an exact match, then don't use like with wildcards.

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` you are wide open for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL SLASH doesnt need to be scaped. You can use slashes in the query without problems.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");
sb.append("WHERE URL = '" + url + "'");
```

This query will work perfectly  if url variable is something like "/path/to/file/"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the slashes, if you only want to return an exact match, then don't use `LIKE`, use `=` -

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");
sb.append("WHERE URL = '" + url + "'");
```